# how to disable jquery mobile markup tag in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I using haml , bootstrap and jquery mobile.
I try to disable jmobile to markup all tag in form.
I add:

```
%script{:src => "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"} 
:javascript
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});
%script{:src => "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"}
```

and in view I wrap form by a div:

```
.disable-markup{"data-enhance"=>"false"}
  = form_for ...
```

**It not effect!**
Then I try to add data-role='none' to each tag (in firebug I see tag have data-role='none')

It still not effect , jquery mobile markup all tag and conflig with bootstrap => my site broken

Please help me to do this :D :D :D

Comment: If I don t want jquery mobile markup all my tag, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use JQM1.1+ instead of JQM1.0.

Refer to
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html